# Error while exporting SQL Server data via OPENROWSET feature

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, export, openrowset

I am using below query to export SQL Server table data to Excel, but I am getting a syntax error as shown below.

> Incorrect syntax near ' '.

Code:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;
Database=\\local\testlocation\users$\Documents\test.xlsx','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') 
SELECT * FROM Test_Date
```

issue occurs in both SQL Server 2016/2008 R2, 64bit

Comment: Just as a side note: you *are* aware that SQL Server 2008 R2 is **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - it's definitely time to upgrade!

Comment: @marc_s it occurs with 2016 version as well :(

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.